# What does "experience on someone" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> KMD was another editor with 30 years of experience on me, and when I would casually flip through an issue of *Time* that she had marked after I had, I would marvel at the things she found.

What does "experience on someone" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, to have *something on someone* means to have that something as an advantage over the person:

> [have (something) on (someone)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+(something)+on+(someone))
>   2. To have a particular advantage over someone.
>   *You may think you can beat me, but I've got 10 years' experience on you.*
>   (TFD)

The speaker is saying that KMD has 30 more years of experience than the speaker, which is advantageous.